# Is the set discrete?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Is the set $S=\{(m+\frac{1}{2^{|p|}},n+\frac{1}{2^{|q|}}):m,n,p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$} discrete in $\mathbb{R}^2$?
>
> I'm not  getting how shall I check discrete here?

Comment: In R^2 or in R?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: The set $S$ is discrete if for every $x \in S$ there is a open set $U_x \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $U_x \cap S = \{x\}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Take a **particular** point $P=\left(m+\frac{1}{2^p}, n+\frac{1}{2^q}\right)$.  We want to show that the point is an **isolated** point. To do this, show that our set contains no point other than $P$ within distance $\min\left(\frac{1}{2^{p+2}},\frac{1}{2^{q+2}}\right)$ of $P$.

Comment: and what will be limit points of S?

Comment: The points of shape $(m+\frac{1}{2^p},n)$ or of the shape $(m, n+\frac{1}{2^q})$ or of the shape $(m,n)$.